# How do I properly install a bootloader for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I've decided to use my laptop to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but I've ran into several issues. I used a USB removable device to install Ubuntu. I noticed that, during the installation, it doesn't recognize Windows 10 at all, so I made the probably very stupid choice to overwrite all my existing data completely.

It would've been all good if I didn't get a fatal error during the installation concerning the bootloader. I tried to boot Ubuntu after the installation nonetheless, and it brings me to a black screen that briefly says "Checking media" and afterwards shows nothing but a flashing underscore. I assume that in the current state, Ubuntu is unbootable.

I try reinstalling, and get no fatal error this time, but the end is the same - seemingly unbootable state.

Lastly, I press the "Try Ubuntu" option to see if I can install grub2 manually, but I don't get access to Wi-Fi. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: For future reference, you need to disable the Windows 10 fastboot option and then you need to shut down windows fully without any type of hibernation before installing Ubuntu or it will not recognize Windows 10.

Comment: You have demonstrated that it's unlikely that your WiFi will work after install. An expert could download and compile the drivers, but it's VERY different than on Windows, and not a task for beginners. Ask yourself if you want to continue.

Comment: As for grub, you should be able to install grub without wifi but you might want to check a few other things first. With newer computers, you can often boot without grub. Can you access the boot options before the computer boots (each manufacturer has a different process)?

Comment: GRUB installation does not, by itself, erase or disable your Windows Boot Manager, it just moves it down the list of OS options to boot from; something else has happened.

Comment: @user535733 You don't need to be an expert to compile drivers. If you can follow basic instructions you can compile drivers. The only hard part is downloading and installing `build-essential` without wifi but if you have access to ethernet it's easy.

Comment: No, as I said, before boot I get nothing but a black screen with the brief "Checking media" and the subsequent flashing underscore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completely black blank screen after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742875/completely-black-blank-screen-after-boot)

Comment: I mean, enter the bios boot options [like this for a Dell](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Booting-error-Checking-Media-Fail/m-p/4237837#M777271). Every manufacturer is different so you may have to press a different key to get to the BIOS or boot options.

Comment: @K7AAY How do I make sure /dev/sda1 is not mounted, like the first answer suggests? It still has the "Win10 SSD" label, so I'm not sure... /dev/sdc1 has the "UBUNTU 20_0" label, so I assume that's the partition I installed Ubuntu in?

Comment: Use the `lsblk` command and there is a column for mount point. If there is nothing listed under the mount point column for the `/dev/sdc1` row, it is not mounted.

Comment: Then it is mounted, because under "mount point" for sdc1 it shows /cdrom.

Comment: You might want to try using [boot repair](https://askubuntu.com/a/828261/167115). You can do this if you have access to ethernet to install it. Do this from the "live" session.

Comment: Due to technical limitations (inadequate end of the ethernet cable), I am unable to acess the internet whatsoever. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Repair/Replace the cable. You need network access. Or, if you're comfortable with the command line and Wi-Fi, you could set up Wi-Fi.